# I cant figure out how to fix this reactjs error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarn-v2

I just pulled a our main branch and my other dev is across the world and cant figure out how to deal with this. When I usually have these errors with eslint I "npx prettier --write" it but this isnt the case here. Any ideas help! This is what it shoots back below.

" Error: Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build
warn  - The `target` config is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deprecated-target-config

Failed to compile.

./components/sections/HowItWorks.tsx
39:62  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
info  - Loaded env from /Users/****/***/landing-page/.env.local
info  - Checking validity of types...

error Command failed with exit code 1."

Please let me know if you have a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Build errors are frequently caused by errors in your code like this
./components/sections/HowItWorks.tsx 39:62 Error: ' can be escaped with ', ‘, ', ’. react/no-unescaped-entities

try to use template strings `` if your text has ' or ", before push to remote repo try to run build and check errors locally